# Flagging vs. close issue

Tags: support, closing, flagging, badges

I have read:

https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close

I haven't earned my Marshall badge yet, and:

https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions

says I should vote to close rather than flag, so how do I earn my Marshall badge?

Comment: You get your Marshall badge by actually flagging flag worthy content.

Comment: how does that work?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: There are several reasons for flagging something. You can flag questions, answers, and comments. In general you can use a flag as a way to contact a moderator in a discrete way. Reasons could, for example, be a comment that is rude, an answer that is a questions, a post that is SPAM, etc.

Comment: Slowly... how else?

Comment: so it's still alright to flag even though the literature says otherwise?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: If you can vote to close, then there is no reason to involve a moderator.

Comment: @Thomas; but then I won't get Marshall

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: You can flag for other reasons than wanting to close.

Comment: @Thomas; so it's not illegal then?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: What is not illegal?

Comment: because the advice is to close not flag, but this is left to my discretion i assume -  i appreciate it's not technically illegal - it's just a phrase. so flag if the post is bad but not closeworthy

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: No, you don't want to flag a question you want closed if you can vote to close it. This would be "illegal". The point is, there are a lot of other reasons you can flag content. And so you can earn the Marshall badge.

Comment: Flagging a post when you should either vote to close it or downvote it, or even vote to delete, is what I call (to myself or to a fellow diamond) a "Mommy, Mommy" -flag (I wasn't the first to call it that). It is signalling that you want a moderator to do something you could do yourself. Or signalling that something  is wrong, you don't know what, but you want somebody else to make the bad things go away. Which is just the modus operandi of toddlers.

Comment: so flagging comments counts towards Marshall? a side point - what happens to declined flags? okay i'm getting the hang of this - i can flag all i like but only helpful flags count

Comment: And if it makes you feel better, I haven't got a Marshall badge either. Some users have gotten it by frivolously flagging everything remotely flagworthy, and earned my disrespect while doing that. Some badges are meant to take a long time to earn.

Comment: Just what exactly do you plan to do with your Marshall badge when you earn it, that makes it so important to you? You won't get much for it on eBay.

Comment: it might have chocolate in it; @GerryMyerson

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I hope I haven't earned your disrespect.

Comment: @Thomas. No way. You didn't try and reach it in 2 months or so. I know, I know. It is more likely that users are just eager to help. Or think they are. Some just get on my nerves. Says more about me, I suppose.

Answer (score 7):

As commenters said, reaching 3000 reputation does not preclude you from earning Marshal badge. You can still flag spam as spam, flag Very Low Quality posts as such, flag answers that should have been a comment as Not an Answer, and flag comments when there is a reasonable case for doing so.

That said: your pursuit of badges has been noticed around the network, so you may want to put less emphasis on it in the future.  ["Spam Voting" - Should we stop it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269082/spam-voting-should-we-stop-it)